# Redcar short name to use editor to commit messages to git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, redcar

You can use TextMate with

```
git config --global core.editor "mate -w"
```

What shortname would I use for the Redcar editor? redcar? car? rcar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git config --global core.editor "redcar -w"
```

Your redcar version needs to be > 0.8.
If that isn't working, it depends on how you have installed redcar.